# Add class issues in Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-mobile-button

I am trying to get the button pressed effect on click of the button in JqueryMobile.
I am able to add the class using css to get this effect onclick on the button, but its not reverting back the previous state(on release).

Below is my index.html code:

```
<div class="loginbutton" id="sgninBtn">  </div>
```

Below is my script code to get the button effect:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sgninBtn", function() {    
$("#sgninBtn").addClass('loginbuttonclick');  
});    

$(document).on("taphold", "#sgninBtn", function() {
$("#sgninBtn").addClass('loginbuttonpressed');
});
```

Below is my css code to get the button effect:

```
.loginbutton {width:300px; height:48px; background:url(../images/samplespriteimage-login.png) 0 0px;}
.loginbuttonpressed {width:300px; height:48px; background:url(../images/samplespriteimage-login.png) 0 -48px;}
.loginbuttonclick {width:300px; height:48px; background:url(../images/samplespriteimage-login.png) 0 -96px;}
```

All these classes are getting applied as needed, but once its clicked and got the particular style its not reverting back to previous style on release of the button.
Is there any on release event in JqueryMobile to make it work.Or is there any way to slove this problem.

I am removing the added classes on pagebefore event.But i ideally want it to happen on release of the button. Please help me on this.Thanks

Comment: you need to remove it after click or tap is done `.removeClass()`. You can translate click event into two events, `mouseup` and `mousedown`. check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/n5WeM/

Comment: @Omar This works fine inn browser(web) but mine is mobile app.Its not working in device.:(

Comment: I have tested the code below in my answer on iphone 5, touchstart and touchend both work. Test it and let me know pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to `.removeClass()` after the event is done.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JnruS/)**

`click` event can be be divided into two events:

1. Start of event `mousedown`, `vmousedown` or `touchstart`. Here, you
   add classes or do other stuff.

   ```
   $('#sgninBtn').on('vmousedown touchstart', function (e) {
     if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
       $(this).addClass('loginbuttonpressed');
     } else {
       $(this).addClass('loginbuttonclick');
     }
     return false;
   });
   ```
2. End of event,  `mouseup`, `vmouseup` or `touchend`. Here, you remove
   classes or do other stuff.

   ```
   $('#sgninBtn').on('vmouseup touchend', function (e) {
     if (e.type == 'touchend') {
       $(this).removeClass('loginbuttonpressed');
     } else {
       $(this).removeClass('loginbuttonclick');
     }
     return false;
   });
   ```

.

Comment: vmousedown touchstart and vmouseup touchend are working fine in device.Thanks a ton :)